# Nothing getting log to file

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I have written the bellow logging configuration file.

```
[loggers]
keys=root,  appName

[handlers]
keys=simpleFormatter,  filelogformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
arts=(sys.stdout,) 

[logger_appName]
level=DEBUG
handlers=appNameHandler
qualname=appName
propagate=1
channel=appName
parent=(root) 

[handler_appNameHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
level=DEBUG
formatter=filelogformatter
args=('/specific/path/on/disk/project.log',) 

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime) s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s %(message)s

[formatter_filelogformatter]
format=%(asctime) s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s %(message)s
```

Only logging to console stdout is working but file it is not.

```
def get_logger(name=None):
    """
    """
    logging_file=os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__) [0], 'logging.conf')
    logging.config.fileConfig(logging_file)
    _logger = logging.getLogger(name) 
    _logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
    return _logger
```